# Asp.net MVC Core - Page rendering partially sometime (Patrial HTML come in response)

Tags: javascript, performance, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, browser

My application build in ASP.Net MVC core framework.

It is working fine in 2 environment but for another 2 environment it breaks the page and page render partially. This is not every time.

My findings is we are serializing Model to global json variable on the client side. Most of the time it breaks there. It send html response till json object.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving HTML instead of JSON then an unhandled exception is being thrown on the server and you are receiving the error page (which has HTML) instead of the JSON payload you are expecting. Turn on Remote Errors for your application, then capture the (now including the error message) html and paste into notepad so you can see what the problem is, and then fix it server side.